# Is there a Github markdown language identifier for Swift code?

Tags: swift, github, markdown

I'm using https://jbt.github.io/markdown-editor online tool for documentation. I'm wondering if there's an identifier to recognize the swift syntax elements.

Thank you.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

````
```swift
struct Animal {
    let nickName : String?
}
```
````

should do it

Comment: Yeah, I thought that's too simple. I was comparing it to the javascript version. Thank you!

Comment: @anitteb Is simple because somebody tell you how it is. Knowledge is power.