# Swift code not highlighted in markdown file when using VSCode

Tags: swift, visual-studio-code, markdown

I have been using VSCode to writing some notes about swift language in markdown. Everything works fine besides the swift code block is not highlighted like other languages.
Tried to install the `Swift Language` extension but didn't solve my problem.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43588383/is-there-a-github-markdown-language-identifier-for-swift-code